# Custom CLI options in Vite/Rollup

Tags: command-line-interface, vite, rollup

I use Vite 4 and I need to specify custom options in the command line to modify my Vite config (`vite.config.js`) based on given values:

`npm run build -- --custom-option=value`

However, the command fails with this error:

`CACError: Unknown option '--custom-option'`

I've only found that Vite blocks custom commands on purpose. Is there a way to bypass it?

If it helps, these are my `scripts` in `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vite",
    "build": "vite build --mode=production",
    "dev": "vite build --mode=development"
  }
```